# Mozzila firefox input file label emulating double input windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, input, label

Clicking on labels is not working in old mozzilas like 19.0
So i used a very simple script to emulate a click

```
if($.browser.mozilla) {
 $("#upload_wall_select_hidden").trigger('click'); 
   }
```

But label click feature is present in version 24.0

So, now this creating two file input windows.
Is there any solution to prevent this

Any way to detect label click feature, browser detection is not a perfect solution

I solved this problem by adding this

```
if($.browser.mozilla) {
$(".trigger-file-input").attr('for',''); 
}
```

Mainly it disable the label

Comment: I didn't understand well, you're triggering a click on a input[type=file] element?

Comment: @AndrésTorres I solved it by removing for attr via jquery in mozzila